# SoftEther VPN Setup: Multiple NIC configuration

Tags: azure, vpn, openvpn, nic

Config:
Windows Server 2019 (VM on Azure)
2 Virtual NICs (Each with a static private address and corresponding public IP address on Azure)

Managed to install and configure SoftEther VPN Server and it works great!

But I am unable to achieve the following configuration:
Let's say I have 
first NIC with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and
second NIC with IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Now, client A, when connected should have his public IP Address as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
And, client B, when connected should have his public IP Address as yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

I have tried to create multiple Virtual Hubs but couldn't find any option to make this mapping.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving VPN server which assigns multiple IPs to clients you can try Clustering function with multiple servers.

But if you only have 2 clients and dont want to use multiple servers then with your above setup **create client1 on VirtualHub1 and client2 on VirtualHub2.**

*I haven't tried it ever but i think it should work.*

Ofcourse make sure VHub1 and VHub2 are bridged to different Network Adapter